# Drawing Circle at CGPoint touchPoint

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I am trying to draw a circle (small like a dot) at the exact point of a `UITouch`.

The problem is, when I get the touchPoint from the user touch, I have to then draw the `Rect` in which to place the circle.

To work out an origin for the Rect, to place it such that, a circle drawn within it will have a centre point at the original touchpoint, I have used Pythagorus' theorem.

However, this approach is not elegant and is not exact.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
UITouch *touch = obj;
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context,(CGRectMake ((touchPoint.x - 5.7), (touchPoint.y - 5.7)
                                                   , 9.0, 9.0)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like below

```
  CFFloat radius=10;
  UITouch *touch = obj;
  CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

  CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context,(CGRectMake ((touchPoint.x - radius/2), (touchPoint.y 
                                              - radius/2)
                                               , radius, radius)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is fine.  What could be more elegant than Pythagorus?  As for accuracy, add a few more digits to the constants and you can be more accurate than both the user's sense of his own finger position and the system calculations giving you the centroid of the touch.

What's more, I can't think of a good alternative. (Maybe one: do this with an image view, where the image is a circle, and set [the view's anchor point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html) so that it positions in the middle of the touch).